# Can the enemy see if you're using a Red or Blue Trinket?

Tags: league-of-legends

If I use a red or blue trinket, can the enemy see that?

The reason why I'm asking is so then as jungler, I can check the usual ward spots and if it's not warded, then I can proceed to gank. But the element of surprise would of course be ruined if they could see that I'm ward checking.

Comment: Enemies can see the animation of the red/blue trinkets on the map (not the mini-map), if they have vision of that spot.

Comment: So in other words, using a red trinket to try to detect wards pre-gank is pointless? Are there any other ways (other than smite on chickens) to detect wards?

Comment: No, its not pointless. If theres a ward, then you can clear it and come back later. If there isnt a ward, then they wont see your trinket, or you, and you can then gank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, its not pointless. If there's a ward, then you can clear it and come back later. If there isn't a ward, then they wont see your trinket, or you, and you can then gank or even wait for a few seconds for a good time to gank knowing that they do not have vision on you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios that can happen when using the red trinket.
If you're aware of a ward in a specific spot, the red trinket actually has the ability to **disable** the ward, preventing vision. If you disable a ward, there is no vision, and you can run a quick gank. If you auto attack the ward, the enemy will get vision of you. The second scenario is that you are seen by the ward, which in this case would likely telegraph a gank attempt. Laners that fail to keep track of their ward timers, can become susceptible to ganks.

When you use the sweeper, if you are in vision, the enemy will be able to see you sweep, which may promote them to harass you or engage on you.

> Summons a drone at the target location for 6 seconds (400 / 600 range). The drone reveals and **disables** all invisible traps and wards within an 400 / 600-unit radius. (120 / 60 second cooldown).

The blue trinket however, will reveal to the enemy team where you are checking if it intersects with their vision/the enemy team's vision.

> Reveals small location within 2500 / 3500 range for 2 seconds (120 second cooldown). Enemy champions hit will be revealed for 5 seconds. This does not affect stealth champions.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Trinket_item